# How do I reference in watch kit extension?

Tags: swift, xcode, watchos-2, watchos-3

I'm not able to make references to outlets created in the Interface Controller in the Extension Delegate. Eg The name of a timer, created in the interface controller, does not come up automatically when I make mention of it in the extension delegate file. It isn't under any private declarations either in the interface controller. I get the error message: "Use of unresolved identifier".

Comment: could you show the code?